# Convert string to Upper and Lower case Turbo Prolog

Tags: prolog, uppercase, lowercase, turbo-prolog

How do I convert a string to Upper and to Lower case in Turbo Prolog.

`string_upper` and `string_lower` function is for SWI Prolog,

I found something like,

```
tolower([], []).
tolower([Upper|UpperTail], [Lower|LowerTail]) :-
char_type(Lower, to_lower(Upper)),
tolower(UpperTail, LowerTail).
```

But didn't get what exactly it is.  Can anyone help me solve this.

Comment: Did you try running the code you are showing? Does it give an error, or just unexpected results? A quick Google search also shows a [different solution](http://objectmix.com/prolog/183135-converting-string-uppercase-lowercase.html) which checks the code range of the character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using upper_lower(),

```
write("Enter string to convert\n"),
readln(Str1),


upper_lower(Str1,Low),
write("In lower case "),
write(Low),nl,
write("In Upper Case "),
upper_lower(Upp,Str1),
write(Upp).
```

The upper_lower Predicate:
The upper_lower predicate can be used to convert uppercase characters to lowercase, or lowercase letters to uppercase. The general form of the predicate is
upper_lower(UpperCaseString, LowerCaseUpperCaseString)